# Passing smarty Variables in a include ( with Codeigniter )

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I'm very newbie to php and codeigniter (and smarty too).

I follow a lot of tutorials and Now I'm confident with my smarty + CodeIgniter configuration, but now I have this escenario. I want to pass a couple of variables into a smarty include in order to show just two strings in the include ( the header, the strings are part of the title )

This is the include (header.tpl):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>{$Titulo} - {$NombreModulo} - Some Static text.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/sitio/contenido/css/Style.css" />
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitio/contenido/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
{/literal}
(some code omitted)
```

and my controller:

```
function index()
{
    //$this->load->view('welcome_message');
    $this->load->library('smarty_parser');
    $datos = array (
    'texto' => 'String de prueba',
    'elapsed_time',1500,
    'TituloPagina','Inicio',
    'Modulo','Dashboard'
    );
    $this->smarty_parser->parse('plantilla.tpl', $datos);
}
```

and the file Plantilla.tpl (the template)

```
{include file="head.tpl" Titulo=$TituloPagina NombreModulo=$Modulo }
<div id="cuerpo">
{include file="sidebars/dashboard.tpl"}
</div>
<div id="contenido"> {$texto} </div>
<!-- fin del contenido -->

</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
</body></html>
```

The problem here is the first line on the last file (or a least I think so). I can put a static string here (`{include file="head.tpl" Titulo="Static Title" NombreModulo="Another one"}` ) and it works, but doesn't work with the way the documentation says.

Clarifying, what I want to accomplish is to send some string variables to the smarty include to be printed on the tittle tags, from the controller.

**UPDATE** The code, when is set up like this, just display - - Some Static text.com

Comment: So what does it display when you have the code set up like this?  Does it just leave the title and module blank, like " -  - Some Static text.com"?  Or does it put the literal variable name in there, like "$TituloPagina - $Modulo - Some Static text.com"

Comment: Just edited the question. The code display " - - Some Static text.com" only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this part is incorrect:

```
$datos = array (
'texto' => 'String de prueba',
'elapsed_time',1500,
'TituloPagina','Inicio',
'Modulo','Dashboard'
);
```

Should be:

```
$datos = array (
'texto' => 'String de prueba',
'elapsed_time' => 1500,
'TituloPagina' => 'Inicio',
'Modulo' => 'Dashboard'
);
```

Comment: thanks. It's hard to admit but this is a very rookie mistake. I had my eyes above the smarty code and I never think the error was in the php code. Thanks, it's working now

Comment: You're welcome... these kind of things are easily overlooked.